# Java code in jsp comment. How it works?

Tags: java, jsp

Theres the code structure:

```
jsp code
<% 
java code
%>
jsp code
```

So, how java-code works in jsp? Can i implement chenges without rebuild?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what you mean by "rebuild." Clearly, for something to run on the JVM, it has to be compiled. However, the JSP container does that for you automatically: it sees that the file has changed, and recompiles it.

Actually, it does a little more than recompile: it first translates the JSP into pure Java code that implements the `Servlet` API, then it compiles that Java code. The static text in the JSP (eg: `<html>` is turned into `println()` calls. The JSTL and other tag references are transformed into Java code that instantiates and invokes a tag handler. Scriptlets are inserted verbatim.

You don't say what JSP container you're using, but most of them will let you examine the generated servlet. Tomcat, for example, stores the generated code under the `work` directory.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/code.html

Changes will be applied just by reloading the page on browser, since it's JSP, which means that the page will be compiled everytime it's loaded.
If you are using Tomcat you can see generated java codes of the JSP in folder: TOMCAT_HOME/work/localhost

It's not wise to use java code on a JSP code because if there's hard to identify syntax error and if there is one, the entire page won't be able to be loaded at all. Unlike PHP which will load until the point where there is syntax error.

Comment: The first statement is not actually true. The average servletcontainer in production suit won't do that. The coincidence will that Tomcat does do that by default. But this involves expensive scans on the local disk file system.

Answer (score 0):

`<%` and `%>` are not comments.  They signal the beginning of a scriptlet, i.e. java code.  If you're using Tomcat, any changes to the jsp files are noted and rebuilt without you having to do anything else.

Comment: Ahem, as Anon said, not just Tomcat.  The servlet's container.